# find a special character in file & remove the special character, before/after words of special character using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

A file contains email addresses. Requirement is to remove words present before/after a special character & also the special character from a file.

e.g.-
file contains email addresses such as:

```
abc.def*cap.com,abc.def.ghi*cap.com
```

file should contain the email addresses such as:

```
abc.com,abc.def.com
```

@(special character), word before @ & one word after @ need to be removed.only one-one word before/after special character need to be removed.

Comment: In your example, you say "the file contains email addresses" but then you give a set of data that doesn't look like email addresses.  Show us the data you are starting with, what you want the output to achieve and what you have already tried.  At the moment this isn't enough information for us to help

Comment: file contains email addresses such as :suresh.rana@capital.com , atul.kr.mishra@capital.com                                       
file should contain such as:suresh..com , atul.kr..com                                      words present just before, just after @ need to be removed & also the special character @.                                                                                       Note- word to be deleted from left/right side of @ upto getting any dot(.), space( ) or ^

Answer (score 2):

I'd use perl or sed

```
$ echo 'abc.def@cap.com,abc.def.ghi@cap.com' | sed 's/[[:alnum:]_]\+@[[:alnum:]_]\+//g; s/\.\././g'
abc.com,abc.def.com

$ echo 'abc.def@cap.com,abc.def.ghi@cap.com' | perl -pe 's/\w+@\w+//g; s/\.\././g'
abc.com,abc.def.com
```